# Pass a variable to a partial in Jade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pug

In Rails, we can pass in a varialbe to a partial by the following:

```
<%= render partial: "myPartial", locals: {:key => "value"} %>
```

How could I do this for Jade?

It seems like I have to use `include` in Jade which is equivalent to `render` in Rails.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
!=partial('myPartial', { locals: { key: 'value' } });
```